# How to make String first letter capital and others small

Tags: java, string

I am trying to convert String first letter as capital and remaining should be small. I tried below code. It's working fine with convert first letter capital but it's converting remaining letter as small.

```
String str = "hiGh";
// capitalize first letter
String output = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1)
```

Output should be: `High`

Comment: What output are you getting instead of the expected? That should tell you what you're missing.

Comment: _"remaining should be small"_ There's nothing in your code to make the remaining text small. You already have split the string and there's the `toLowerCase()` method available, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could manipulate the characters of a `String` to make sure that only the first one is uppercase,

```
String capitalizeFirstOf(String s){
 char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
  for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
   if (i==0){
    chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[i]);
   }else{
    chars[i] = Character.toLowerCase(chars[i]);
   }
  }

  return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the later substring to the lowercase.
Use the following code:

```
String name  = "hiGH"; 
name = name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score -1):

If your doing much string converting i would recomend using a libary like:
[apache commons 3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

They have e.g. `UpperCase/LowerCase/SwapCase/Capitalize/Uncapitalize` etc.

So you don't have to put you time on simple string methods.